# ncurses curs_set(0) not working in vscode integrated terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, xtermjs

Currently coding in C++20, using Ubuntu WSL2.

Using the code shown below, the cursor goes invisible when running the program in WSL2 in Windows Terminal, working as intended.

However, when running the program in WSL2 in vscode's integrated terminal, the cursor is visible throughout the whole program (just in case, I even put `terminal.integrated.scrollback` to 0).

The function `curs_set(0)` doesn't return `ERR` when it runs in either of the terminals. Is this a problem with vscode's integrated terminal? Is there a way to fix this?

Code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {

    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    

    if (curs_set(0) == ERR) {
        addstr("Not working");
    }
    mvaddstr(1, 1, "Random sentence.");
    refresh();

    getch();
    mvaddstr(2, 1, "Random sentence number two.");
    getch();

    endwin();

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the terminal emulator (xterm-js).

Comment: @Locklan Are you using the DOM renderer by any chance? Just figured, that DECTCEM does not work there (see https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/3502).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue on my end by calling `refresh()` once first before using `curs_set()`.