# Can't install curses package

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, python-curses

I'am trying to run

```
pip install curses
```

in the CMD put it returns the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses
```

I am using Python 3.12.0 on VS Code and trying to use the curses package but can't install it , I installed the package windows-curses `pip install windows-curses` in the CMD, but it didn't work as expected and couldn't call it like the videos on the internet like:

```
curses.curs_set(0)
```

I also tried `pip3 install curses`, but it didn't work.

So probably there is a difference between curses and windows-curses.

Comment: What happened when you tried `curses.curs_set(0)` after installing `windows-curses`?

Comment: are you getting any specific error when you call `curses.curs_set(0)` ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 
nothing happens

Comment: @nisakova  
no errors

Comment: when you type : curses. the IDE should automatically complete the syntax , it's not doing it

Comment: @mkrieger1 nothing is happening

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: did you try `curses.refresh()` first and then `curses.curs_set()` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511685/ncurses-curs-set0-not-working-in-vscode-integrated-terminal

Comment: that is C++ you are talking about , meanwhile I am coding python @nisakova

Comment: “ but it didn't work”, What are the error message?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses  @Hermann12

Answer (score 0):

For you can use `pip install windows-curses` to install package.

Then use python codes `import curses` to use it.

Please note that even though you installed a package called `windows-curses`, you still import it using `import curses`. This is because `windows-curses` is a Windows-compatible version of the `curses` module, not a separate module.